# render nested partial for new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, renderpartial

I'm trying to render a _new.html.erb partial from a comments controller inside a posts controller.

My comments resources is nested in my posts resource

routes.rb

```
  resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :new]

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    resources :memorybooks
  end

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/channel',    to: 'static_pages#channel'
  match 'login', to: 'static_pages#login'
  match '/posts', to: 'posts#new'
  match '/users', to: 'users#new'
```

My _new.html.erb partial in my comments controller:

```
   <%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :comment %>
      <%= f.text_field :comment %>

      <p>
      <center>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      </center>
    <% end %>
```

My comments controller method:

```
def create
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
    redirect_to @current_post
else
    render '/'
end
end
```

In my show.html.erb file, when I use the following:

```
<%= render 'comments/new' %>
```

The _new partial form appears, but when I post, I get the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/comments"
```

And if I use the following line in show.html.erb

```
<%= render new_post_comment %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_post_comment'
```

Below is my rake routes

```
               users POST   /users(.:format)                               users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                           users#new
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#show
       post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)             comments#index
                     POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)             comments#create
    new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)         comments#new
   edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit
        post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#show
                     PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update
                     DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#destroy
    post_memorybooks GET    /posts/:post_id/memorybooks(.:format)          memorybooks#index
                     POST   /posts/:post_id/memorybooks(.:format)          memorybooks#create
 new_post_memorybook GET    /posts/:post_id/memorybooks/new(.:format)      memorybooks#new
edit_post_memorybook GET    /posts/:post_id/memorybooks/:id/edit(.:format) memorybooks#edit
     post_memorybook GET    /posts/:post_id/memorybooks/:id(.:format)      memorybooks#show
                     PUT    /posts/:post_id/memorybooks/:id(.:format)      memorybooks#update
                     DELETE /posts/:post_id/memorybooks/:id(.:format)      memorybooks#destroy
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)                               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                           posts#show
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                           posts#destroy
                root        /                                              static_pages#home
             channel        /channel(.:format)                             static_pages#channel
               login        /login(.:format)                               static_pages#login
                            /posts(.:format)                               posts#new
                            /users(.:format)                               users#new
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: probably @post is nil when rendering the partial. i guess the html output of the products/show renders the new comment form with the action "/comments", right?

Comment: yeah, source code shows "/comments".

Comment: how do you assign values to @post, @comment?

Comment: not sure what you mean...  users make new posts, which then get a post Id.  When I'm on the post url, then I get the current post info with @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id]) ... now I'm trying to post a comment to that post...

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the @post populated. Add a <%=@post.inspect %> and a <%=@comment.inspect %> in comments/_new and see what's displayed in the browser

Comment: you're right.  when named post it returns nil, but if i name it something else, like current_post it returns an object.  why would that be?

Comment: got to the error now.  thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<%= render new_post_comment(@post, @comment) %>
```

I hope that can help you.